# Adding to db not working

Tags: delphi, ado

I do a query to see if Asset number is in the data base,  It returns false, Thus I then want to Add the data to the db ,  i get no errors. but it never adds the data.

```
  //check if its there, if so update it, if not add it.
if fdeptlayout.adoquery1.IsEmpty then
begin
  showmessage('adding new machine to db');
  with Fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1 do
    begin
    sql.Clear;
    sql.BeginUpdate;
    sql.add('INSERT INTO MList ');
    sql.Add('(Zone,Dept,Number,Name,Asset,IsPanel');
    sql.Add(',FinalLocation,Left,Top) ');
    sql.Add('VALUES ( :Zone, :Dept, :Number, :Name, :Asset, :IsPanel');
    sql.Add(', :FinalLocation, :Left, :Top)');
    sql.EndUpdate;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Zone').Value  := CZone;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Dept').Value  := CDept;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Number').Value := CNumber;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value  := CName;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Asset').Value := CAsset;
    Parameters.ParamByName('IsPanel').Value := CIsPanel;
    Parameters.ParamByName('FinalLocation').Value := CFinalLocation;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Left').Value := CLeft;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Top').Value := CTop;
    open;
```

Comment: What's the error message? BTW in SQL there should be `VALUES` not `VALUE` (youre missing an S), if you change that does it work then?

Comment: there is no error message, and changed value to values still nothing

Comment: if i replace update with Open;   i get an santax error "INSERT INTO"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you are using `adoquery1` for getting the data and send a command.

**You must not do that.**

### Using Append

You can append data direct to your open dataset

```
with Fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1 do
begin
  // append a new row
  Append; 

  // set data to all fields
  FieldByName('Zone').Value := CZone;
  FieldByName('Dept').Value  := CDept;
  FieldByName('Number').Value := CNumber;
  FieldByName('Name').Value  := CName;
  FieldByName('Asset').Value := CAsset;
  FieldByName('IsPanel').Value := CIsPanel;
  FieldByName('FinalLocation').Value := CFinalLocation;
  FieldByName('Left').Value := CLeft;
  FieldByName('Top').Value := CTop;

  // post the new added data to the dataset
  Post; 
end;
```

### Using SQL-Command

You have to use a seperate instance of a query to perform a sql command

```
with TADOQuery.Create( nil ) do
try
  // Prepare
  Connection := Fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Connection;

  sql.add('INSERT INTO MList ');
  sql.Add('(Zone,Dept,Number,Name,Asset,IsPanel');
  sql.Add(',FinalLocation,Left,Top) ');
  sql.Add('VALUES ( :Zone, :Dept, :Number, :Name, :Asset, :IsPanel');
  sql.Add(', :FinalLocation, :Left, :Top)');

  Parameters.ParamByName('Zone').Value  := CZone;
  Parameters.ParamByName('Dept').Value  := CDept;
  Parameters.ParamByName('Number').Value := CNumber;
  Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value  := CName;
  Parameters.ParamByName('Asset').Value := CAsset;
  Parameters.ParamByName('IsPanel').Value := CIsPanel;
  Parameters.ParamByName('FinalLocation').Value := CFinalLocation;
  Parameters.ParamByName('Left').Value := CLeft;
  Parameters.ParamByName('Top').Value := CTop;

  // Execute the statement
  ExecSQL;

finally
  Free;
end;

// Update the data
Fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Refresh;
// or even better
Fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Requery;
```

Comment: the append worked perfect! so if i return 1 record, and i want to edit that one record, i do same thing just dont add Append. Correct and it would update that one record?

Comment: Just write that what you want to do. If you want to append a new record, then use `Append`. If you want to edit an existing record then use `Edit` :o)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to execute the query:

sql.ExecSQL

The Update is probably interpreted as Self.Update, i.e. a visual update of the form.

Comment: added that in place of update;  i now get "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Comment: What database are you using? Are you sure it's not INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...  (plural)?

Comment: Two other possibilities (I do not use ADO but dbExpress, so I'm not sure these apply here)
1) Is sql.ParamCheck true?
2) You never define what your parameters should be:
Params[0].DataType = ftInteger;
Params[0].ParamType = ptInput;
etc.

Comment: i never set paramCheck to true,  let me try with setting it to false..as long as its false then i should not have to define ..correct?

Comment: No, ParamCheck must be true so that the code checks the SQL for the existence of parameters. Which you need.

Comment: ok set to true, ill try setting the paramType, there all strings though